# Creating Console App to Read and Display Numbers from a File

Tags: c#, arrays, console-application

MY problem now with my program is that it is not displaying the values in the data file properly. It is showing all 0's in a sorted fashion. It is not relaying the actual numbers in an ascending fashion.

> ====================================

The 25 numbers that need to be read in and placed in an array are: (Only used 4 numbers to keep the post shorter.

```
10.5
20.1 
33.0 
45.9
```

> =================================

My code so far is below: I think my issue is in my DisplayArray() method. It writes out all 0's like this:

```
\Users\Joe\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CIS110\Program11\prog11Dat.
was opened
0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    Press any key to continue . . .
```

=======

```
class Program11
    {
        const string INPUT_FILE_NAME = "\\Users\\Joe\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\CIS110\\Program11\\prog11Dat.Txt";

        static double[] numArray = new double[25];
        static StreamReader fileIn;

        static void ReadFile()
        {
            if (File.Exists(INPUT_FILE_NAME))
            {
                fileIn = (File.OpenText(INPUT_FILE_NAME));
                Console.WriteLine("{0} was opened",INPUT_FILE_NAME);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0} does not exist\n",INPUT_FILE_NAME);
                ConsoleApp.Exit();
            }            
        }


        static void DisplayArray()
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < numArray.Length; i++)
                Console.Write("{0}    ", numArray[i]);


        }

        static void SortValuesAscending()
        {
            uint i, j, k;
            double tempValue;

            for (i=1; i<=(numArray.Length); i++)
            {
                k = 1;
                for (j = (i + 1 ); j <= numArray.Length -1; j++)
                    if (numArray[j] < numArray[k])
                        k = j;
                if (k>i)
                {
                    tempValue = numArray[k];
                    numArray[k] = numArray[i];
                    numArray[i] = tempValue;
                }
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            ReadFile();
            DisplayArray();
            SortValuesAscending();
            DisplayArray();


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is your *exact* problem that you need help with? at the minute your question is too broad

Comment: @Sayse - I apologize, just wanted to give as much info as possible. I have two issues I am needing help with. One is calling methods:

In Main() call ReadFile() to load numArray. Next, call DisplayArray() to display the contents of numArray. Next, call SortValuesAscending() to sort the numArray. Lastly, call DisplayArray() again to display numArray.

So I guess I could start with that, to help narrow down my issue.

Comment: Your main method is already calling 3 of those 4 methods, you just need to call `DisplayArray` again. It is much better (most of the time) to try and make your question as concise as possible, whilst not leaving out important details, so when reading, it is very easy to see where the problem lies

Comment: Thank you. I will edit my question to shorten it. I am new here and just wanted to be as informational as possible.Thank you.

Comment: Updated question to shorten and include a more specific error. Code included. I was able to call DisplayArray() again. I was not thinking that I just needed to literally call it again in Main(). The only other problem I see is that my array is not going to be displayed on the console app. I have a return statement in DisplayArray().

Comment: I think theres a lot that needs addressing here and its not really something that can be quickly answered, your `ReadFile` should handle not only reading in the whole file, but assigning the lines from the file to the array (which `DisplayArray` does currently), `DisplayArray` should then just be a for loop to write out all the values

Comment: updated post with new information. Thanks for the help it's starting to come together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its getting there, your problem is that your `ReadFile` doesn't do any reading at the minute; nor does it add to the array of doubles

```
static void ReadFile()
{

    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
    if (File.Exists(INPUT_FILE_NAME))
    {
        using(var sr = new StreamReader(INPUT_FILE_NAME))
        {
            string line;
            while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                lines.Add(line);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: {0} does not exist\n",INPUT_FILE_NAME);
        ConsoleApp.Exit();
    }

    // you now have a list of numbers as strings here (lines)
    // You need to parse and assign these to your numArray
    // Hint: for loop and Parse/TryParse
}
```

I've intentionally left out how to do the parsing to help with your learning :)

A second hint, in your `DisplayArray`, look into using [`PadRight`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34d75d7s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is a one line method that will take a file name, read the numbers (one per line), and print them out in a sorted order:

```
    public void PrintNumbersInFile(string fileName)
    {
        File.ReadAllLines(fileName) // reads the lines in the file into a string[]
            .Select(l => double.Parse(l.Trim())) // for each item in the string[], parse the string into a double after trimming any spaces around it
            .OrderBy(n => n) // sort by the value of the double
            .ToList() // put the sorted values in a list
            .ForEach(n => Console.Write("{0:F1}    ", n)); // and for each item in the list, write out its value ({0:F1} to show one decimal point)
    }
```

Note that this assumes the file exists and is in a valid format, so it will throw otherwise...

And using the sample input you had in your questions (putting it in a file), this is the output:

```
10.5    20.1    33.0    45.9    Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

You are blindly reading the lines in the file into a fixed length array of 25. Use a list or initialize your array based on the line count. Also you are not checking for empty lines. If you have a stray CRLF at the end of the file then the File.Read will successfully read one empty line.

Also 'j = (i + 1) ... numArray[j]' will exceed the array when i == numArray.Length - 1.